# Error in downloading a file from server to client in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to download a file to client machine. Below is the code I was used in another application but now in my this current application this throws an error on `Response.End()`.

I found [from here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us) that use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`  instead of `Response.End()`.

But now error disappears and code runs all but download process still can't be started. I tried different type of codes by searching on the internet but in vain:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Please note that I also used try catch in `Thread.ResetAbort()` but no download starts.

My code which I am currently using is as below:

```
 string fileName = "Mifare.txt";

 File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Mifare.txt"), text);

 Response.ContentType = "text/txt";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;

 filename=" + fileName + ".txt");

 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Mifare.txt"));

 Response.End();
```

Please any one can help me. Please also note that on the same page I am using crystal reports `pdf` and excel download methods and they works fine. but on this method to download a text file i face errors.

Below is the my code which is on the same page to download `crystal report` in `pdf` format which works fine.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ReportDocument repDoc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];        
    Response.Buffer = false;        
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    try
    {            
        repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
           Response, true, "Mifare");                        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Thread.ResetAbort();
    }
}
```

Comment: just remove the .End()

Comment: Thanx Kelmen! But removing .End() doesn't work. I can't understand what is the problem with this current page. Now at the end I created a new page Filedownload.aspx and wrote all my code there on page load. On current page's button click event I just write the content in file and saved to server, and redirect to the Filedownload.aspx and all works fine. It seems that the problem was in my current asp.net page but I could not understand what was the problem.

Comment: For clarification: You want to export a report to PDF and then download it to the client machine where the report is being viewed?

Comment: then try insert Response.Flush() b4 the End().